# iPython ssh from Windows qtconsole to a remote iPython kernel

Tags: windows, ssh, ipython, paramiko

I want to run an iPython kernel on a Linux box and then connect to it remotely on a windows machine. The ipython kernel works fine and I can connect a qtconsole to it locally on the Linux box.
On Windows I have installed ipython and paramiko as its ssh client.
I run the following command on Windows 7 x64 cmd

```
D:\...\.ssh>ipython qtconsole --IPythonConsoleApp.sshserver='user@hostname:22' --IPythonConsoleApp.sshkey='myKey' --IPythonConsoleApp.password='1234'
```

I get the following error:

```
[IPythonQtConsoleApp] Could not setup tunnels
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\frontend\consoleapp.py", line 289, in init_ssh
    newports = tunnel_to_kernel(info, self.sshserver, self.sshkey)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\kernel.py", line 245, in tunnel_to_kernel
    if tunnel.try_passwordless_ssh(sshserver, sshkey):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\ssh\tunnel.py", line 87, in try_passwordless_ssh
    return f(server, keyfile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\ssh\tunnel.py", line 123, in _try_passwordless_paramiko
    look_for_keys=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 332, in connect
    self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 493, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
SSHException: not a valid DSA private key file
```

The key is even created with RSA.

Has anybody had a success in connecting remotely from a Windows machine to a remote ipython kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> The key is even created with **R**SA.

but

> SSHException: not a valid **D**SA private key file

RSA and DSA are different algorithms.

Either create a DSA private key file, or configure ipython to use RSA.

(I am not familiar with ipython, so cannot advise on the specifics. Sorry.)

Comment: Good point. I thought it had to support RSA and the error was simply a side effect of another problem. But creating a DSA key solved that exception. Still, I can not connect to the remote iPython kernel. The error reads `*** Failed to connect to hostname:22: TypeError('must be string or buffer, not bool',)`. I guess I should post it as another question.

Comment: I've successfully used RSA keys with paramiko. I received this error when one of my parameters was off (it *should* have told me that the username was wrong/missing, but instead it faulted the key for some reason!) I would try going into the python shell and playing with it, see if changing some of the parameters changes its behavior.